# Approaching the limit of CSS transform scale

Tags: css, transform, css-transforms

For my project [areallybigpage.com](http://areallybigpage.com) (*), I'm trying to see how far we can with CSS' `transform: scale(...)`.

This works and displays the text at normal size:

```css
#id1 { position: absolute; transform-origin: 0 0; transform: scale(10000); }
#id2 { position: absolute; transform-origin: 0 0; transform: scale(0.0001);}
```

```html
<div id="id2"><div id="id1">Bonjour</div></div>
```

**But this seems to be too much and doesn't display anything anymore** (tested Firefox 32.0/Win7, laptop computer/few hardware acceleration):

```css
#id1 { position: absolute; transform-origin: 0 0; transform: scale(100000); }
#id2 { position: absolute; transform-origin: 0 0; transform: scale(0.00001);}
```

```html
<div id="id2"><div id="id1">Bonjour</div></div>
```

**Is there a limit of scale with CSS3 `transform: scale(...)` ?**

**How can we push this limit further?**

---

(*) : *I currently* don't use  *`transform: scale(...)` on this page, because of the limitation described in this question, but I would like to use it in a future version of this website.*

*Off-topic: if you zoom far enough with <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, you easily get to the `1.79e+308` float limit problem. (but this is another problem)*

Comment: Both work for me on Firefox 37, Firefox 34, and Firefox 24.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Google Spy.

Comment: Screenshot on Firefox 32.0 / Win7 : http://gget.it/4n4lwoxq/3.jpg

Comment: I see the problem on Chromium, but not on Firefox. Maybe it's because of the graphics, I have basic (OMTC) acceleration, but not GPU acceleration.

Comment: On my Chrome `39.0.2171.95 (64-bit) / MacOs 10.9.4` it seems that `9999` is the highest admittable value

Comment: I think it has to do with [maximum CSS px](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mozilla2:Units#Proposal).

Comment: I do not see these limits when using `scale3D` in Chrome. This might be because `scale3d` is hardware accelerated. They still seem to exist in Firefox and IE. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54q4pfgh/)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it seems that in your test, **at least for firefox*** the maximum height in CSS px is an issue.
*(*In chrome the maximum `scale()` multiplier/divider seems to be 10000)*

If you add a third div with a fixed position, and you set your divs to this maximum CSSpx you can see that the higher the multiplier/divider is, the smaller the inner divs are :

```js
s=150000;
document.getElementById('p').addEventListener('click', function(){
    s*=1.1; doit();}, false);
document.getElementById('m').addEventListener('click', function(){
    s/=1.1; doit();}, false);

function doit(){
    document.getElementById('id2').style.transform = 'scale('+1/s+')';
  document.getElementById('id1').style.transform = 'scale('+s+')';
  document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = s;
  }
```

```css
#id1 {  transform-origin: 0 0; transform: scale(1); width:17895697px; height: 17895697px; background:#AA00AA;}
#id2 {transform-origin: 0 0; transform: scale(1); width: 17895697px; height: 17895697px; background:#00AA00; }
#id3 { position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%;background:#AFAFAF;}
#p {position: fixed; top: 3em;}
#m {position: fixed; top: 3em; left: 3em;}
#r {position: fixed; top: 4em;}
```

```html
<div id="id3"><div id="id2"><div id="id1">Bonjour</div></div></div>
<button id="p">+</button><button id="m">-</button><p id="r"></p>
```

**Check this answer for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24748165/3702797.**

If we take the test case in the other way (container multiplies then contained divides), I can go to a multiplier of `10000` in chrome and `64424503296.0000038...` in FF :

Chrome

```
#id1 { transform: scale(10000);  width: 33554428px; height: 33554428px; background: #AA00AA; }
#id2 { transform: scale(0.0001); width: 33554428px; height: 33554428px; background: #00AA00; }
```

Firefox

```
#id1 {  transform: scale(10000);  width: 17895697px; height: 17895697px; background:#AA00AA; }
#id2 {  transform: scale(0.0001); width: 17895697px; height: 17895697px; background:#00AA00; }
```

[Chrome Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xc54nqL0/)           [Firefox fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trnsoj2p/)

### Edit

This does mean that for firefox, the maximum `scale()` multiplier is equal to the `maximum browser CSS height/width` / `element height/width`. If your calculated element's height/width exceeds this limit, then your element won't be scaled anymore.

```js
r.textContent = document.getElementById('id2').getBoundingClientRect().width +" instead of 1px*20.000.000";
```

```css
#id2 {
  transform: scale(2e+7);
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #00AA00;
}
#id3 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #AFAFAF;
}
#r {
   position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="id3">  <div id="id2"></div> </div>
<p id="r"></p>
```

Chrome doesn't seem to be limited in such a way however…

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido for your answer. So this basically means that there is no *real solution* (that would work cross-browser) for going up to `scale(1000000);`? Do you have an idea on how to go further?

Comment: This does mean that for firefox, the maximum scale() multiplier is equal to the `maximum browser CSS height/width` / `element height/width`. check update for an example with a 1px*1px element. For Chrome, it seems to be limited to `infinity`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it to be an issue with browsers, but more to do with the PC you're running it on.

*Hardware acceleration/graphics acceleration* would play a **big** part in how your page is displayed, and so you may need to factor this into your 'page'.

> *Many of you probably already know about this but for the rest, here's a quick tip that you might find useful.*
>
> **Quick tip:** If you use Chrome or Chromium browsers and **hardware acceleration** is disabled for your graphics card, you can try to
>   force it to get better video playback performance (for instance on
>   YouTube) as well as support for features such as the 3D Earth view in
>   the new Google Maps.
>
> To check if your Chrome / Chromium browser uses hardware acceleration,
>   open a new tab, type: `"chrome://gpu"` (without the quotes) and look
>   under "Graphics Feature status" - all (or at least most of) the
>   features should say "hardware accelerated". [see more...](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/enable-hardware-acceleration-in-chrome.html)

You graphics card also plays a huge role in speed of rendering/etc, and so I wouldn't ***completely*** steer clear of use of the `transform: scale(...)`, but would mention to any visitors that 'for best results, allow hardware acceleration and ensure your graphics drivers are up-to-date...'

But realistically, do you need this ability? Could you not use a different approach? (i.e. if you were using this idea to 'generate a background effect', for example, could you not use svg/pseudo effects/etc?).

---

In conclusion, I don't believe this is a bug, but I think it would be a way of seeing 'who's got the better hardware acceleration'/'graphics ability' with their browser/pc combination.

**Further Reading**

- [unleash the power of Hardware-Accelerated HTML5 Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh562071.aspx)
- [How to enable or disable software rendering in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2528233)
- [GPU Accelerated Compositing in Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any limit for `transform:scale(...)`. On the latest version of Chrome, I got up to 10 000 000 with no problem. But your problem might not be `transform:scale(...)` if you have a very small text that you make bigger with it. There is a limit for how small `font-size:...`, it can't be smaller than 0.01px. If you don't have such a small text, I don't see why you would like to have such a high value for `transform:scale(...)`, the text would be too big for anybody to be able to read it.